# function names() and function testCraps() aren't working correctly. Can anyone figure out why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to put together two functions and I can't for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong.

1. Function names() is supposed to repeatedly ask the user to input a name. When the user ceases to enter names, the program should print the amount of times each name was entered. This is what I've got so far.

   ```
   def names():
       counter={}
       name=input('Enter next name:')
       while name!='':
           if name in counter:
               counter[name]+=1
           else:
               counter[name]=1
           name=input('Enter next name:')
       for name in counter:
           if counter[name]>1:
           print('There are {1} students named {2}.'.format(counter[name], name))
       else:
           print('There is {1} student named {2}.'.format(counter[name], name))
   ```

It works up until I stop inputing names. At that point, it just gives me a syntaxerror stating "unexpected EOF while parsing." Anyone know what I need to fix?

2. Function testCraps() is supposed to take a positive integer n as input and simulate n games of the dice game, craps. It should then return the user's win rate after n games of craps. Here, I've got:

   ```
   def craps():
       import random
       dice=random.randrange(1,7)+random.randrange(1,7)
       if dice in (7,11):
           return 1
       elif dice in (2,3,12):
           return 0
       else:
           newRoll=random.randrange(1,7)+random.randrange(1,7)
       while newRoll not in (7,dice):
           newRoll=random.randrange(1,7)+random.randrange(1,7)
       if newRoll==dice:
           return 1
       else:
           return 0

   def testCraps(n):
       count=0
       for i in range(n):
           if craps()==1:
               count+=1
       return count/n
   ```

For some reason, testCraps() always seems to give me 0, and I can't see any sort of problem with it. Can you see something I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps you missed the part about needing to indent the body of a function definition?

Comment: for 1, Use `raw_input` in place of `input` as you are using python 2.x

Comment: for the second function, dividing 2 ints in python2 automatically uses integer division. cast one of them as a float before dividing (ie `float(count)/n`)

Comment: @N.Aylett Welcome to StackOverflow! Just for the future, keep in mind that each question on the site should be for a separate issue, because you can only choose one answer as correct. It also allows better titles than generic "functions don't work".

Comment: Thanks, guys! I got them both working! I knew it was probably one small mistake on both of them. The indents were just a mistake with formatting my question. They were correct in the actual program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `names()` is that when string formatting you should index starting at `{0}` not `{1}`. After correcting this and the indentation it works fine:

```
def names():
    counter={}
    name=input('Enter next name:')
    while name!='':
        if name in counter:
            counter[name]+=1
        else:
            counter[name]=1
        name=input('Enter next name:')
    for name in counter:
        if counter[name]>1:
            print('There are {0} students named {1}.'.format(counter[name], name))
        else:
            print('There is {0} student named {1}.'.format(counter[name], name))

names()
```

Interactive session:

```
Enter next name:Galax
Enter next name:Test
Enter next name:Galax
Enter next name:
There is 1 student named Test.
There are 2 students named Galax.
```

Here's the craps code, with the indentation fixed and the casting to float suggested in one of the comments above:

```
def craps():
    import random
    dice=random.randrange(1,7)+random.randrange(1,7)
    if dice in (7,11):
        return 1
    elif dice in (2,3,12):
        return 0
    else:
        newRoll=random.randrange(1,7)+random.randrange(1,7)
        while newRoll not in (7,dice):
            newRoll=random.randrange(1,7)+random.randrange(1,7)
        if newRoll==dice:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

def testCraps(n):
    count=0
    for i in range(n):
        if craps()==1:
            count+=1
    return float(count)/n

print(testCraps(100))
```

Sample Output:

```
0.44
```